# Is a collection of important programming vocabulary/phrases on topic?

Tags: discussion

### Some Background

I am a Computer Science major in the United States with a passion for the French Language. I find frequently that I do not have the vocabulary to express myself (as with an foreign language), but specifically I find that I can say nothing relevant to Computer Science or Computer Programming in French.

## The Question

Would it be on topic to create a collection post dedicated to translations of important programming vocabulary and phrases? I imagine this would be Community Wiki, but I'm not sure.

### Reasons For

I've seen other "collection" questions on other StackExchange sites (most notable Mathematics, but there are others). These tend to be lists of relevant theorems or history, but can also be "tips and tricks" as on Programming Puzzles and Code Golf. If memory serves, however, PPCG uses a meta question...

It would also serve as an invaluable reference question for those who need this kind of thematic dictionary.

### Reasons Against

It's not particularly well-suited for the Q&A format, as there is no "correct" answer (hence the Community Wiki suggestion).

Additionally, it raises the question: where do we draw the line? Are all such thematic dictionary reference questions on topic? Do we limit them to only work-related fields? What criteria can we establish?

---

#### Finally

If it does become on topic, what guidelines are important to the question and answers to *keep* the thing on topic? (Or should I ask a separate question for that in the eventuality it happens?)